# Linq XML reader not working

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

My XML is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Supplier xmlns="http://www.example.com/xsd/2012/09/">
  <ID>10302</ID>
  <AccountingUnitId>10000</AccountingUnitId>
  <ShortName>FRE</ShortName>
  <AccountNumber>601100</AccountNumber>
  <BankAddress>...</BankAddress>
  <SupplierAddress>...</SupplierAddress>
  <TermsOfPayment>
    <ID>10009</ID>
    <ShortName>14 NETTO</ShortName>
    <Name>ohne Abzug 14 Tage netto</Name>
    <DaysNet>14</DaysNet>
    <Standard>false</Standard>
    <ValidFrom>1997-01-01T00:00:00.000+01:00</ValidFrom>
  </TermsOfPayment>
  <TermsOfPayment>
    <ID>10040</ID>
    <ShortName>2,0-14</ShortName>
    <Name>2,0 % Skonto innerhalb 14 Tage</Name>
    <DaysForDiscountFirst>14</DaysForDiscountFirst>
    <DiscountPercentFirst>2.0</DiscountPercentFirst>
    <DaysNet>30</DaysNet>
    <Standard>false</Standard>
    <ValidFrom>1997-01-01T00:00:00.000+01:00</ValidFrom>
  </TermsOfPayment>
</Supplier>
```

I want to read the ID of the Supplier and all child elements of `TermsOfPayment` and I wrote the code like this:

```
XNamespace ns = "http://www.example.com/xsd/2012/09";
var accountingunit = (from ele in XElement.Parse(textresult).Elements(ns + "TermsOfPayment")
                     select new node
                     {
                         TermsID = (string)ele.Element(ns + "ID"),
                         idvalue = (string)ele.Element(ns + "AccountingUnitId"),
                         shortname = (string)ele.Element(ns + "ShortName"),
                         name = (string)ele.Element(ns + "Name"),
                         Daysnet = (string)ele.Element(ns + "DaysNet"),
                         discountfirst = (int)ele.Element(ns + "DiscountPercentFirst"),
                         discountsecond = (int)ele.Element(ns + "DiscountPercentSecond"),
                         daysdiscountfirst = (string)ele.Element(ns + "DaysForDiscountFirst"),
                         daysdiscountsecond = (string)ele.Element(ns + "DaysForDiscountSecond"),
                         Termsstandard = (Boolean)ele.Element(ns + "Standard"),
                         ValidFrom = (string)ele.Element(ns + "ValidFrom"),
                         ValidTo = (string)ele.Element(ns + "ValidTo"),
                     });
```

But I am getting `null` if I try to read the `accountingunit` variable:

```
foreach ( unit in accountingunit)
{
}
```

Comment: So don't keep us in suspense! What happens when you run that code? Or is it another game of Guess the Error!

Comment: Please, "not working" is not enough to describe your issue. Are you receiving errors? Is `accountingunit` not what you're expecting?

Comment: You can generate an xsd from your xml with xsd.exe then generate classes from the xsd (also with xsd.exe). You can then just parse your xml with an XmlSerializer. Then get the information you are interested from your class.

Comment: @k4rlsson How would that help: getting `XmlSerializer` to handle anything other then the XML it generates is an exercise is frustration. Easier to use any other API.

Comment: @Richard What do you mean by that? I use it all the time, you can parse an xml to a class structure with ~5 rows of code.

Comment: When i run the code to Foreach loop it says

Value can not be null.
Parameter name: element

Comment: @user1514428: Because you are trying to access elements that don't exist. The first `TermsOfPayment` node is missing the "Discount" nodes.

Answer (score 2):

Your namespace is wrong. You have:

```
XNamespace ns = "http://www.example.com/xsd/2012/09";
```

But the XML specifies:

```
http://www.example.com/xsd/2012/09/
```

You are missing the trailing `/`, which will prevent any elements from matching. Once that's corrected, you will also need to consider the root "Supplier" node; you don't have to get to it by name, but you could do:

```
from ele in XDocument.Parse(textresult).Root.Elements(ns + "TermsOfPayment")
            ^                           ^
```

Lastly, each `TermsOfPayment` node has different child elements. You will have to first check for their presence otherwise you will get further errors running your code.

Answer (score 1):

[`XContainer.Elements(name)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348975%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) only looks for the named elements amongst its immediate children. But there is no `TermsOfPayment` that is a child of the document root.

Perhaps you wamt:

```
…XElement.Parse(textresult).Elements(ns+"Supplier").Elements(ns+"TermsOfPayment")
```

Comment: Or, rather than use Elements(), use Descendants()

Comment: @TomRedfern Indeed, but I tend to avoid that for the same reason as avoiding `//` in XPath: for larger XML documents it can lead to a lot of searching…

Comment: indeed indeed. I concur, but almost everyone I know uses shorthand xpaths, as fully qualified xpaths are horrible looking, and we all know that code should be beautiful.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of problems :

- Supplier is in namespace `xmlns="http://www.example.com/xsd/2012/09/`, yet you are defineing `XNamespace ns = "http://www.example.com/xsd/2012/09";` (note the missing trailing slash
- Also, several of the elements, such as `DaysForDiscountFirst`, `DiscountPercentFirst` and `DiscountPercentFirst` are not present in both child `TermsOfPayment` nodes - you'll need to do some additional parsing here before you hard cast these in your projection to `node`.

Comment: Thank you StuartLC, Actually the Namespace is correct in the code but typing mistake here in post.

Answer (score 0):

For read/write on XML file, I use XMLSerializer. It's very simple :

You have to create a class :

```
public class Supplier
{
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public int AccountingUnitId {get;set;}
    public string ShortName {get;set;}
    public int AccountNumber {get;set;}
    public string BankAddress {get;set;}
    public string SupplierAddress {get;set;}
    public TermsOfPayment termPayment[] {get;set;}
}
```

With your class :

```
public class TermsOfPayment
{
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public string ShortName {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public int DaysNet {get;set;}
    public bool Standard {get;set;}
    public DateTime ValidFrom {get;set;}
}
```

For write :

```
Supplier SupplierTest = new Supplier();
XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Supplier));
using (StreamWriter wr = new StreamWriter("supplier.xml"))
{
    xs.Serialize(wr, SupplierTest);
}
```

For read :

```
XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Supplier));
using (StreamReader rd = new StreamReader("supplier.xml"))
{
    Supplier SupplierTest = xs.Deserialize(rd) as Supplier;
}
```